# Making a $http request returns undefined in a couple different ways

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, q

I'm just starting out with Node.js and I am trying to make a pokedex with pokeAPI , I'm having an issue using $q and $http requests. When I attempt to make the api call it brings back "ReferenceError: getPokes is not defined". While trying to figure out what was causing it , I've found putting getPokes on a variable causes the error to go to "ReferenceError: response is not defined". Maybe I don't need it there and I'm misunderstanding the logic. Either way I know I am missing some important piece of logic , maybe something in my controller? Any and all help is immensely appreciated!

EDIT: I've since found that if i remove pokeName from this.willCollectThemAll it brings back the $http requests with where pokeName is in the request and shows undefined (http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ + pokeName. Which makes sense as it's not getting passed in , but it's showing the $http completing , unlike where if I put in pokeName into this.willCollectThemAll where it says function getPokes is undefined which is where I'm stumped.

SERVICE:

```
// INITIALIZE SERVICE
// ============================================================
angular.module("app").service("pokeService", function($http, $q, $timeout) {
// ============================================================
this.willCollectThemAll = function(pokeName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var pokemon = false;
    var morePokemon = false;
    var pokemonCaught = false;
    var allPokemonCaught = false;


    getPokes = function(pokeName) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokeName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log('service:', response);
            pokemon = response.data;
            pokemonCaught = True;
            checkAllPokemon();

        })
    }
    getMorePokes = function(pokeName) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/' + pokeName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log('service:', response);
            morePokemon = response.data;
            allPokemonCaught = true;
            checkAllPokemon();

        })
    }

    function checkAllPokemon() {
        if (pokemonCaught && allPokemonCaught) {
            if (pokemon && morePokemon) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(true)
            }
        }
    }
    console.log('service', response)
    getPokes();
    getMorePokes();
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

});

Controller:

```
// INITILIZE CONTROLLER
// ============================================================
angular.module("app").controller("pokeCtrl", function($scope, $q, pokeService) {

// VARIABLES
// ============================================================


// FUNCTIONS
// ============================================================
$scope.willCollectThemAll = function() {

    pokeService.willCollectThemAll($scope.pokeName.toLowerCase())
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(pokeService, response);
            $scope.pokeData = response;
        })
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I could see couple of issues with your code, number one is you must return your $http calls which you are missing. Try the following in your service

```
this.willCollectThemAll = function(pokeName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var pokemon = false;
    var morePokemon = false;
    var pokemonCaught = false;
    var allPokemonCaught = false;


    getPokes = function(pokeName) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokeName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        })
    }
    getMorePokes = function(pokeName) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/' + pokeName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        })
    }

    function checkAllPokemon() {
        if (pokemonCaught && allPokemonCaught) {
            if (pokemon && morePokemon) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(true)
            }
        }
    }

    getPokes().then(function (data){
        pokemon = data;
        pokemonCaught = true;
        checkAllPokemon();
    });

    getMorePokes().then(function (data){
        morePokemon = response.data;
        allPokemonCaught = true;
        checkAllPokemon();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: I've tried as you suggested sadly it brings back this error
     ReferenceError: response is not defined

     at Object.willCollectThemAll (pokeService.js:50)

     at ChildScope.$scope.willCollectThemAll (pokeCtrl.js:12)

Answer (score 0):

This thing looks like it's had a run in with a Charizard.

Once again I think @AliBaig has the right of it but the application logic itself is faulty.  I think you are wanting to chain the promises such that you get more pokemon if you don't getem all the first time.

Here's a quick swag at your code.

```
this.willCollectThemAll = function(pokeName) {
    // $q.when() is a nice shortcut for this logic and creates a new promise each time.
    //var deferred = $q.defer();
    var pokemon;  // prolly better to make these empty arrays then check for length instead of checking for boolean value.
    var morePokemon;
    var pokemonCaught = false;
    var allPokemonCaught = false;

    // getPokes returns a promise.
    var getPokes = function(pokeName) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokeName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        })
    }
    // getMorePokes also returns a promise.
    var getMorePokes = function(pokeName) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/' + pokeName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        })
    }

    // If you resolve the promise here you will be trying to resolve the same promise multiple times.
    function checkAllPokemon() {
        if (pokemonCaught && allPokemonCaught) {
            if (pokemon && morePokemon) {
                //deferred.resolve(true);
                return true;
            } else {
                //deferred.reject(true);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Have getPokes() return a promise and give this promis back to the controller.
    return getPokes().then(function (data){
        pokemon = data;
        pokemonCaught = true;
        // In either case here we're gonna return a promise.
        if ( !checkAllPokemon() ) {
            return getMorePokes().then(function(data) {
                morePokemon = response.data;
                allPokemonCaught = true;
                //returning pokemon with ES6 syntax cuz I'm lazy.
                return checkAllPokemon() ? $q.when([...pokeman, ...morePokemon]) : $q.reject('Did not getem all. :(');

            });
        } else {
            // If we already have the pokemon don't bother chaining again.
            return $q.when([...pokeman, ...morePokemon]);
        }
    });
}
```

Note there are a slew of error paths that should be properly accounted for.